# Cannot use Ubuntu 17.10 ISO image for installation

Tags: usb-installation

While trying to write the ISO on an USB stick I get the following error
"It looks like this is not a bootable image"

[image: Error screenshot]

(Note: I can write Ubuntu 16.xx without any problem with the same software)

Comment: No my problem is different. I have added more detail.

Comment: What happens if you press Continue and try to boot from it?

Comment: Did you sumcheck the iso?

Comment: I have first tried to do this by using built-in "Startup disk creator" but it failed to load the iso file without showing any error.

Comment: No, sorry I dont know how to sumcheck the iso.

Comment: And if I try to extract this iso somewhere on my harddrive to see the contents, this error shows: "Failed to read volume info: 'First volume descriptor type not primary like ISO9660 requires''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-download Ubuntu iso install images from [Ubuntu Releases](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)

Then follow these Ubuntu tutorials:

[How to verify your Ubuntu download](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu?_ga=2.37567072.1170558116.1522984024-1570023986.1517891776#0)

[Create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0)